# FCM Foreground and Background notification layout view and PendingIntent

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm creating notification using Firebase and FCM

```
class FcmServices: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage)
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
    }

    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        val notifTitle = remoteMessage.notification?.title
        val notifBody = remoteMessage.notification?.body

        val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder?
        val notificationManager =
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId = "101"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "notification", importance)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, notificationChannel.id)
        } else {
            builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext)
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, NotifikasiActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_bprmsa)
            .setLargeIcon(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    this.resources,
                    R.drawable.logo_bprmsa
                )
            )
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(notifTitle)
            .setContentText(notifBody)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)

        var alarmSound: Uri? = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        if (alarmSound == null) {
            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
            if (alarmSound == null) {
                alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            }
        }
        builder.setSound(alarmSound)
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        builder.priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH
        notificationManager.notify(Random().nextInt(), builder.build())

    }

}
```

I need to open the *NotificationActivity* after click the notification received from Firebase, but the problem is the `PendingIntent` is not working while the app is in **background** state. Is there any different condition between **foreground** and **background** state code ?

And for the second, the *layout* of **foreground** and **background** is also different (**background** state without the icon shown)

[image: notifications]

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Based on the official document from Google, it is intentional. The Icon and any other buttons or others you wish to display other than the title and the message won't display if your app is not running foreground.